# Protect SPA (Eg. AngularJS) + Public REST Api from content scraping

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, screen-scraping

Imagine you have a CMS where all CRUD actions are handled through a REST API.

The SPA consists of an adminpanel (backend) and another Single Page Application for the frontend.

Securing all the protected API calls from the backend with jwt (tokens) is easy, but since all content is also delivered through the public side of the REST API (for non-logged in users), I guess you could see many websites actually stealing and feeding from your entire content: blog posts, categories, products, pages, sidebars etc...

This is the only problem I really see in SPA with eg AngularJs, so is there a way around the problem? Is it possible to make not only admin/backend systems with Angular+REST, but also use it for the frontend, without facing the problem with content scraping as I just mentioned?

If yes, how would you prevent malicious content theft through your API's and still serve your visitors with your site's content?

Comment: Not an answer, but possibly a step in the right direction: nonce

Comment: How is that different from traditionnal web apps/sites? They also serve content over HTTP. The content is (X)HTML instead of JSON, but that's almost as easily scrapable. As soon as content, whatever the format, is available anonymously on the Internet, someone can scrape it.

Comment: Thanks both of you, for your comments. TheSharpieOne: I think a server-generating nonces on each request would defeat the whole purpose of client-side rendering (SPA), but appreciate your input. JB Nizet: I still think providing a public queryable API for all the content of your website, like we do with Angular SPA's is like asking other websites to implement the api's as well... traditional text/html scraping seems like a little more work, and you cannot hook a system to fetch from it automatically, in real time. Well you can, but it'll be more work I guess...

Comment: Facing exactly the same problem. Messing with the service response to confuse the scraper is possible but if this will be the only option for me, then I'll simply forget Angular.